# How should incrementing a package revision be handled when adding/editing a .bbappend file?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I would like to modify a bitbake recipe supplied by Poky. I can make the needed modifications with a .bbappend file from another layer, but I assume that because the package version and revision will remain unchanged, opkg will not notice and update this package on systems which already have it installed.

My first thought was to simply set the `PR` var from within the .bbappend file, but my fear is that `PR` could latter also be changed by the upstream layer (Poky) causing conflicts.

Comment: I think you can use PR or PV in your .bbappend and it will always trump the value in the original recipe. The challenge there is if they go bigger than yours, it might cause issues. I use this for a kernel .bbappend where I need to control that value, but it doesn't override the original because the original doesn't use it.

Comment: You can also increate `PE` variable. By the way, if your layer has bigger priority, it will override everything.